# How to backup growing file?

Tags: file, backup

I have a file that is constantly growing by appending to the file. Every once in a while I want to back it up. The file is too large so copying it every time is not an option.
What I want is that each time I back it up, only the new appended data will be copied. Is there an existing tool that does what I need?
I couldn't find any existing solution. Traditional backup tools such as `rsync` doesn't seem to work the way I need (the file is being copied from scratch)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the expected size of the new additions, you could write a script which includes: `tail -500 filename > save_new_entries.out`.  This will print the last 500 lines to a file which you can then save as a partial backup. This could all be done in a script.